# Torsion of particular form

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

Let $M$ be a 2D smooth manifold and let $\nabla$ be a flat connection on $M$. Denote by $T$ its torsion tensor. In a certain application, torsions of the form
$$
T(X,Y) = X(f)\, Y - Y(f)\, X,
$$
where $f$ is a real-valued function on $M$,
seem to play an important role. I wondered whether a torsion of that particular form has a name, and whether it is known to be relevant in other contexts.

Comment: What you've written doesn't even make sense, as the left-hand side has no $f$ on it. You intend something to which you input two vector fields *and* a function and get a vector field as an output? This certainly is not a tensor field.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant to say that the exists a function $f$, such that the torsion is of that form.

Comment: Note that a torsion of that form can be rewritten as $$T = d_\nabla(\psi\,\operatorname{Id}_{TM}).$$